# form index in inlineformset

Tags: python, django, formset

I have a `formset` created using `inlineformset_factory`. It doesn't matter what it looks like to answer this question. In the template I am looping through it with `for form in forms.formset:`

I want to be able to display the form index of the form in my template. By form index, I mean the number associated with that form in all of the formfields. Is there a variable that does this? I tried `form.index` and `form.form_id` and `form.id` is a field.

Comment: As Daniel says, I don't see anywhere in the source where the index is stored, aside from the `foo-index` string stored in `form.prefix`.

Comment: I assume the loop should be `for form in formset.forms:` (or just `for form in formset:`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, objects in a collection don't generally have access to their index or key.

However if you're outputting the formset in a template, you're presumably looping through the forms. So you can use `{% forloop.counter %}` to get the index of the iteration.

Comment: I ended up needed to do this {% forloop.counter|add:'-1' %} since the counter is 1 indexed and my object is 0 indexed. But this worked.

Comment: In fact you can use `forloop.counter0` to get a 0-index counter.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not pretty, based on the [formset source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/forms/formsets.py#L420) and the comment by @yuji-tomita-tomita above, you could do something like this in your template:

`{{ form.prefix|cut:formset.prefix|cut:'-' }}`

This just takes the form prefix string, which includes the form index, then removes the irrelevant parts. In the view you could simply do e.g. `form.prefix.split('-')[1]`.